# Корректный разбор json_decode

Tags: php, json

Подскажите, как корректно разобрать получившийся JSON ?

`a:1:{s:8:"response";a:2:{s:5:"count";i:3;s:5:"items";a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:2;s:7:"from_id";i:0;s:4:"date";i:1592635773;s:4:"text";s:8:"тест";}i:1;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:3;s:7:"from_id";i:1;s:4:"date";i:1592635978;s:4:"text";s:10:"Отзыв";}i:2;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:4;s:7:"from_id";i:2;s:4:"date";i:1592636040;s:4:"text";s:10:"тест 2";}}}}`

Читал, что это `serialized` данные, но `unserializ'ить` их не выходит
Все бы вроде ничего, но при запросе, например, `$data->response->count` он выдаст `i:3;`, а нужно просто `3`

Comment: Это НЕ json, а сериализованная строка.

Comment: @u_mulder когда я делаю `unserialize`, то получаю `b:0;`. Делаю в виде `$test2= unserialize($test1);`.

Comment: @steam.apk2 если строка в переменной $data, тогда так: `echo unserialize($data)['response']['count'];`

Comment: Всем спасибо. Нашел ошибку в коде